# how to make a permutation method accepts a single positive integer?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

This is my code:

```
public static void permutation(int n) {
    String x="";
    if(n==1) {

        System.out.println(x+"1");
        System.out.println(x+"3");
    }else {
        String temp=x;
        System.out.print(temp+"1");permutation(n-1);
        System.out.print(temp+"3");permutation(n-1);
    }

}
```

I try to wrap my brain around this problem for hours. This method is supposed to accept only one int(>=1); then display all the permutation using only "1" and "3" but stay in the same length as the argument. It got me the correct numbers of permutation but most of the values are wrong. I don't want to return anything from this method. This method is supposed to print results of permutation.

For example: if I give this method an integer of "2", it's supposed to display:

```
 11
 13
 31
 33
```

Instead, what I got is

```
 11
 3
 31    
 3
```

Comment: It doesn't return anything because you have no `return` statements.

Comment: What do you mean by "method doesn't return anything"? Your method is declared with return type `void` so it *can't* return anything. Did you mean that method doesn't *print* anything? Also what exactly are you expecting method to "return"?

Comment: show us some sample input and output

Comment: "*I don't want a return type for this method*" doesn't clarify anything because methods *must* have *some* return type (even if it is `void`). So your question still requires some clarification. For instance what you expect your method to do (what is expected result, for what input, and what you get instead?).

Comment: Those are not permutations but more like combinations with replacement. Also, shouldn't the output be `11, 13, 31, 33`?

Comment: What if the input is 3?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
public static List<String> permutation(int n) {
    if(n==0) {
        return Arrays.asList("");
    }
    return permutation(n-1).stream()
            .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(p + "1", p + "3"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: While I agree that this is a better way to approach the problem, without any explanation I doubt that this will be of much help to OP...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work. By printing the prefix to the "permutation" (actually, it's more like combinations with replacement) immediately, the prefix is only printed *once* for all the "permutations" that should have that prefix. Thus, you get `11 3 31 3` instead of `11 13 31 33`. Instead, you can pass the prefix as another parameter to the method:

```
public static void permutation(int n, String prefix) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        permutation(n-1, prefix + "1");
        permutation(n-1, prefix + "3");
    }
}
```

If you do not want to change the signature of the method, you can create a second method having the single `int` parameter, calling the second method as `permutation(n, "")`.

```
public static void permutation(int n) {
    permutation(n, "");
}
```

Comment: Is there any way for me to use a variable inside the method instead of parameter?

Comment: @MaxLander Not really, since that variable would have to be carried over to the next recursive invocation. You _could_ use a static variable, or a class member when wrapping the method into a special permutation class, but that will make it massively more complicated. Or have the method return the permutation, then you'd not need the parameter either, as in the other answer. But as I said, you can just provide a second method without the additional parameter as an entry point.